# Jupyter/IPython: how to get results in traditional mathematical notation?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, sympy

I have been using WxMaxima for my symbolic calculations for a while now. The good thing about WxMaxima is that you can get formatted outputs right in the program and then export them to LaTeX format with a click of the mouse.

Now I want to try the Jupyter/Ipython plus sympy for multiple reasons. I know how to use `display(Math(r' some LaTeX math here '))` but what I want is to have the result/output of a cell in a nice mathematical form; something like the `TraditionalForm[]` command in Mathematica.

I would appreciate if you could help me know if/how I can get that right in a Jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 3):

I think I found the proper solution and it is a sympy feature rather than Jupyter/IPython one. As explained [here](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/printing.html):

> If all you want is the best pretty printing, use the `init_printing()` function. This will automatically enable the best printer available in your environment.

and

> In the [Jupyter/]IPython notebook, it will use MathJax to render LATEX.

Then one can right click on the output and select `Show Math As > Tex commands`:

[image]

to get the LaTeX output.

P.S. A more proper formatting can be achieved via [galgebra library](https://github.com/brombo/galgebra). I will look into that and add it here later.